# How to run python egg (present in azure databricks) from Azure data factory?

Tags: pyspark, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory, egg

So I created a small pyspark application and converted it to an egg. Uploaded it to dbfs:/FileStore/jar/xyz.egg. In ADF I used jar activity. But in Main Class Name textbox i am confused what to provide.[image]

My Pycharm application has three files, two of them are basically Utility files that contains utility functions that I call and the content of main file is:

Main.py

```
from CommonUtils import appendZeros
from sampleProgram import writedf


def main():
    appendZeros('zzz')
    writedf()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now what to specify in 'Main class name' textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** Main Class Name is "The full name of the class containing the main method to be executed. This class must be contained in a JAR provided as a library."

The following table describes the JSON properties used in the JSON definition:

[image]

Reference:  "[Transform data by running a Jar activity in Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-jar)".

Hope this helps.

---

If this answers your query, do click “Mark as Answer” and "Up-Vote" for the same. And, if you have any further query do let us know.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for replying.. Can you give an example on my code written in my asked question? What will be mainClassName in that case?