# Execute egg directly from Azure Data Factory

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, egg

### Question

*How to execute egg file from Azure Data Factory (AD) pipeline?* Currently I'm able only to call Databricks notebook from where executing egg file. Any way to do that directly?

### What have been done

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57765991/how-to-run-python-egg-present-in-azure-databricks-from-azure-data-factory/58057198#58057198),  I got the following exception:

```
{
    "errorCode": "3201",
    "message": "Must specify one jar or maven library for jar task, either via jar_uri or libraries.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Execute Egg",
    "details": []
}
```

[image]

### Code and structure

On my local machine I can execute `python dist/hello_world-1.0-py2.7.egg`, that will print `'Hello world!'`

```
src
 |-__init__.py
 |-main.py
__main__.py
setup.py
```

*setup.py*

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='hello-world',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    py_modules=['__main__']
)
```

*__main_ _.py*

```
from src.main import run

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

*src/main.py*

```
def run():
    print('Hello world!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-troubleshoot-guide

Comment: What about defining `class Main: @classmethod def main(cls): return run()` and then specifying `Main` as the *Main class name*?

Comment: @a_guest it doesn't work. Looks like my egg get executable only when in the root there is a `__main__.py` file with `if __name__ == '__main__':` section. If I replace this code with a class, I can't run `python dist/hello_world-1.0-py2.7.egg`

Comment: @NicoNing Message `Must specify one jar...` for 3201 is not documented at the link you've provided. I even can't find a proof that is possible at ADF.

Comment: @VB_ I meant to include that class into `__main__.py` and then use it as `if __name__ == '__main__': Main.main()`.

Comment: @a_guest how it'll change the situation? The current problem is that ADF can't execute `__main__.py:__main__` method. What you want to specify at `Main class name` field?

Comment: @VB_ What's the purpose of the "Main class name" field then? I'm not familiar with ADF but it sounds like it wants to `from ... import Main` and then execute it. What else would "Main class name" refer to?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you selected Jar activity in Azure Data Factory, instead of Python activity.

[image: Databricks activities in Azure Data Factory]

In the Jar activity, the "Main class name" expects full name of the class containing the main method to be executed. This class must be contained in a JAR provided as a library.

If you select Python activity, you can specify Python file name and upload your egg library.

[image]

You can find more details about it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-python